# Raster calculator: Missing areas in output using two mosaics

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, mosaic

I'm doing a simple DEM minus DSM to get tree canopy heights. However my results are missing most of the data (no data).

I've used the Minus tool and Raster Calculator achieving the exact same result. The DEM/DSM are mosaic datasets which I am assuming is part of the problem. Tiles do work individually. Rasters are floating point if that helps and I have tried building footprints, overviews and boundaries.

[image]

Comment: Does your DSM totally cover your DEM? Is your data local or over a network? What format are your tiles in? Is spatial reference defined for *everything*, even the tiles?

Comment: The tiles are all .tif and both DSM/DEM tiles match exactly. Data is currently local and everything projected to the same projected coord NZGD_2000.

Comment: It sounds like you've got the basics covered, it may indeed be a problem with the mosaic dataset reading either or both areas. You may need to export your mosaic datasets to single images to run the calculation or tile-by-tile using arcpy.

Comment: Perhaps converting footprints to polygons and set environment extent to it. Weird... Also try output to grid stored in folder, no fgdp, no TIFF.

Comment: I tried a mosaic dataset from fgdb and got the same result. Mosaicing to new rasters worked in the end so it must be a problem with the mosaic datasets.